# How to open Android source code in Eclipse ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I am new to Android development and I have downloaded Source code of Cameraapp from Google web site from following locaiton:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera
```

I am trying to build and compile it into the Eclipse ADT environment. However when I open the folder using File> Import> Android> select existing project, I do not see the folder being able to be selected as a project.

I also noticed that there is no Android Manifest file inside this folder. How is this possible?

I read somewhere that camera app does not have its own Android Manifest file but it uses manifest file from the Gallery App. Which may be right. But my question is that how can I even compile this application?

Or would I have to compile the entire android application folder? Hopefully that is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have manifest file in the project then you have no option than to `create an empty android project` and copy the corresponding `res/` and `src/` file to your empty project.

Then modify your manifest file to define your activities and permissions. Then you can build and run your project in your ADT workspace.

Comment: But the real question here is that how and why Google did post camera App source code without any manifest file? is there anything that I might had missed while loading it?

Comment: I am also new to Android development. So I would guess the purpose is to define your own custom manifest file with permissions that suit our requirements. However I went to that link and I saw **git clone** link is available on top. So install EGit plugin in your Eclipse ADT and then you can import project using **File->Import->Team->Team Project set**.

Comment: yes I have already cloned the repo on my local. And trying to open it on my local. I am not sure what am I doing wrong...